# How to write matrix form for an eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have an eigenvalue problem to solve; for the coupled linear equations

$\lambda A_n=-\alpha_nA_n+A_{n+1}+A_{n-1}-\beta_nB_n$

$\lambda B_n=+\alpha_nB_n-B_{n+1}-B_{n-1}+\beta^\ast_nA_n$

I want to transform it into the standard form like
$X~\vec{p}=\lambda~\vec{p}$; with $X$ being the matrix and
$\vec{p}$ being the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}
           A_{n} \\
           B_{n} \\
           \end{bmatrix}$
. My question is how to make a valid $X$?. I tried but if my matrix $X$ is to include all entries e.g., $A_{n\pm1}$ and $B_{n\pm1}$, then $\vec{p}$ gets modified. For simplicity, I took $n=1,2$ only. 
Is there a valid workaround in place? Thanks.

Comment: What are $A_n$ and $B_n$? Finite, infinite, or double-sided infinite, sequences? If it is not the last case, what are the boundary-case equations?

Comment: $A_n$ and $B_n$ are (in physics context) amplitudes at a particular site $n$. they are finite, but the simplest case could be $n=1,2$, just to check. Do you mean boundary conditions? In that case; $A_{n\pm1}$, $B_{n\pm1}$ could be taken as 1.

Comment: I mean, how many equations (and variables) are there? What is the complete set of values that $n$ runs through? $\mathbb{Z}$ (all integers)? Or all positive integers (in this case, what are the equations for $n=1$ - this is what I call a boundary case)? Or, say, integers $1\leq n\leq N$ (then, what are the equations for $n=1$ and $n=N$)?

Comment: Okay I see.. the case corresponds to $1\leq n\leq N$ and a definite plane-wave form needs to be imposed like $A_n=ae^{ikn}$. $N$ can be taken as 2, for the simplest case. $\alpha_n$ is constant.

Comment: Then what is, say, the first equation when $n=1$? What are $A_0$ and $B_0$?

Comment: $n=1,2$ would mean simply that we have 4 equations, two corresponding to $\lambda A_{1,2}$ and and two $\lambda B_{1,2}$.

Comment: just $A_0=a$, $B_0=b$; when $n=1$; $\lambda A_1=-\alpha_1A_1+A_2+A_0-\beta_1B_1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84714/discussion-between-metamorphy-and-atoz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion revealed that it is a system of, say, $2m$ equations, with $n$ running the values of $1,\ldots,m$, and with $A_0=B_0=A_{m+1}=B_{m+1}=0$. If we choose $(A_1,\ldots,A_m,B_1,\ldots,B_m)$ as a representation of the vector space of solutions, then the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}-A & B \\ B^\star & A\end{bmatrix}$, where
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & \alpha_2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & \alpha_3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ & \cdots & & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \alpha_{n-1} & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & \alpha_n\end{bmatrix},\qquad B = \mathrm{diag}\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}.$$
(Update: this can easily be adapted to $-N_p\leq n\leq N+N_p$ appeared in comments to the OP.)